# discord.js how can i get desc value from the json file

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

i loaded the json file in data when i run `console.log(data[key].use)` command i get a response

```
[ { name: 'Devour',
    desc:
     'Consumes a target tree to gain 7 health regeneration for 16 seconds. Consuming a ward or Ironwood Tree doubles the heal amount.\n\nComes with 3 charges.  
Can be used on an allied hero to give them one Tango.\n\nTree Range: %abilitycastrange%\nWard Range: 450' } ]
```

how can i get `desc` value

i tried `data[key].use.desc` but gives me `undefined`

Comment: Can you try `data[key].use[0].desc` ? I think the result you are getting is an array

Comment: new issue in some places its `active` some its `passive` or even `toggle` instead of `use` what can i do ?
if i do || it is giving me `[0] cannot read the property of 0`

Comment: never mind got it